# How can i send packages on a Minecraft Client (With Fabricmc) and receive it on a Bukkit Server?

Tags: bukkit, minecraft-fabric

I'm a Chinese secondary school student,so my written English may not very well.
How can i send packages (like some words) on a Minecraft Client (Use a Fabricmc Mod to send) and receive it on the bukkit server on MC Multiplayer?

Answer (score 1):

This is done using what's known as the 'plugin messaging channel'. Take a look at [this Fabricmc wiki](https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:networking) to read about client networking (messaging). See [this Spigot wiki](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/bukkit-bungee-plugin-messaging-channel/) on the plugin server-side messaging channel; ignore that this wiki talks a lot about bungee, it's just because that's a common use case. You can make your own channel.

The code below is copied from said wikis and is very much pseudo-code:

**Client**
Sending from the client

```java
PacketByteBuf buf = PacketByteBufs.create();
buf.writeBlockPos(target);
ServerPlayNetworking.send((ServerPlayerEntity) user, TutorialNetworkingConstants.HIGHLIGHT_PACKET_ID, buf);
```

Receiving on the client

```java
ClientPlayNetworking.registerGlobalReceiver(TutorialNetworkingConstants.HIGHLIGHT_PACKET_ID, (client, handler, buf, responseSender) -> {
    client.execute(() -> {
        // Everything in this lambda is run on the render thread
        ClientBlockHighlighting.highlightBlock(client, target);
    });
});
```

Where you see `TutorialNetworkingConstants.HIGHL...`, that's the [Identifier](https://maven.fabricmc.net/docs/yarn-21w05b+build.11/net/minecraft/util/Identifier.html) for the channel.

**Server (Spigot/Bukkit)**
Sending from the server

```java
player.sendPluginMessage(this, "YourChannelName", out.toByteArray());
```

Receiving on the server

```java
@Override
public void onPluginMessageReceived(String channel, Player player, byte[] message) {
    if (!channel.equals("YourChannelName")) {
      return;
    }
    ByteArrayDataInput in = ByteStreams.newDataInput(message);
    String data = in.readUTF();
    ...
```

Take a thorough read of those tutorials, they should cover all you need to know. Just be sure to unregister your channels on both the client and server.